# Infinite loop behind SSL proxy on non-standard port

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, nginx, proxy

I need to run a WordPress instance on a non-standard SSL port (8080). I'm using Docker containers and nginx as a reverse proxy.

Here's the relevant portions of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    # no ports are open besides 80 internally exposed

(...)

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

And for `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        server_name domain.com;
        listen 8080 ssl;

        ssl_certificate certs/domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/domain.key;

        # Proxy parameters
        #proxy_set_header       Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;

        proxy_buffering on;

       location / {
            proxy_pass      http://wordpress;
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

`proxy_set_header Host $host;`

to

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

fixed the issue.

([source](https://rschu.me/how-to-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-with-https-nginx-and-your-ghost-blog-1ae4b1ee07eb))

Comment: OMG this solved me so much headache! Thank you!!!

Comment: @moshe I'm happy to help!

Comment: Solved for me, too.  Thank you!

Comment: For anyone wondering why, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx.  "$host equals $http_host, lowercase and without the port number".  Since we're on a non-standard port, we need $http_host, which includes the port number.